# Single.php template for Taxonomy Term

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type - Films. It has a taxonomy of Film_cat, which in turn has two terms/categories - Term1 & Term2.

For each single post within Term1, I would like to display a specific single.php template. Each single post within Term2 should also have it's own single.php template.

I am currently utilising taxonomy-film_cat-term1.php for the taxonomy archives templates, however can't find any info on how to create different single.php templates based on the taxonomy term.

Answer (score 0):

you can create `single.php` page by renaming it according to your  `custom post type` name.
For Example:

```
   Your custom post type Name: Films
   Your single.php will be: single-films.php
```

So you can find all the posts of the `film` on `single-films.php`.Hope I have cleared my self

Comment: Thanks, but I need to find a single post of a Custom Post Type > Taxonomy > Taxonomy Term. Does that make sense?